# How to dropdown arrow at right side in IntlPhoneField

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to set the dropdown arrow at right side, next to +92, but it is not happening.

here is the code

```
 Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: IntlPhoneField(
                    
                    showDropdownIcon: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      
                      labelText: 'Phone Number',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                    ),
                    initialCountryCode: 'PK',
                    onChanged: (phone) {
                      print(phone.completeNumber);
                    },
                  )),
```

[image]

kindly please help how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope I think your problem has been solved just change `IconPosition` is `trailing` instead of `leading`

```
 Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
      height: 50.0,
      child: IntlPhoneField(
        showDropdownIcon: true,
        iconPosition: IconPosition.trailing,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Phone Number',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
        ),
        initialCountryCode: 'PK',
        onChanged: (phone) {
          print(phone.completeNumber);
        },
      ),
    ),
```

And my Widget Image ->[image]
Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: but there is no property of ```iconposition``` in ```IntlPhoneField```

Comment: are you try my code?

Comment: This code is run on my machine try my answer I have attached output of my screen

Comment: yes, tried urs, is gives me error on iconposition

Comment: which version do you use for flutter

Comment: the latest one, 2.5.1

Comment: I used same version `2.5.1` and `intl_phone_field: ^2.1.0` current dependency above code is work on machine not giving any error what was the error on your machine?

Comment: @TimeToCode I have updated my answer please check it and let me know I also attached my Widget pic also please check it and let me know.

Comment: @VMi is it's correct answer

Answer (score 0):

just you can use

```
 Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
  height: 50.0,
  child: IntlPhoneField(
    showDropdownIcon: true,
    dropdownIconPosition: IconPosition.trailing, // <= Use This ******
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Phone Number',
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
    ),
    initialCountryCode: 'PK',
    onChanged: (phone) {
      print(phone.completeNumber);
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).